# get the filename of a given URL using PHP and remove the file extension

Tags: php, string

I have a little snippet that grab's the filename, including the extension.

```
$currURL = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

given a url... `http://www.somewebsite.com/pretty/url/here/this-is-a-page.php` it returns `this-is-a-page.php`.  I would like to be able to return simply, `this-is-a-page`.

I'm pretty obsessive about doing stuff like this in as little code as possible... how would you do this in a simple and elegant manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$name = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Test:

```
$arr = array('http://www.example.com/path/to/page.php',
             'http://www.example.com/path/to/page.php?a=b&c=d#e',
             'http://www.example.com/path/to/page.x.php',
             'www.example.com/path/to/page.php',
             '/path/to/page.php');

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    $name = pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    echo $name . '<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
page
page
page.x
page
page
```

Comment: Sorry I had to edit to remove my upvote. This fails with `http://www.example.com/path/to/page.php?a=b&c=a.d` because it treats th string as a filesystem file, not as a URL.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to hear that, especially since it answers the question as stated.  At least you found a bug in PHP's pathinfo().

Answer (score 2):

```
$file_no_ext = preg_replace(
    array('#^.*/#', '#\.[^./]+$#'), '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

e.g.

```
http://example.com/fds.php/path/file
=> file
http://example.com/fds.php/path/file.php
=> file
http://example.com/fds.php/path/file.php2.php?abc=a
=> file.php2
```

Another solution is

```
$file_no_ext = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr(strstr($url,'.php',TRUE),strrpos($url,'/')+1)
```

or

```
preg_match('/[^\/]+(?=\.php)/',$url,$match);
echo $match[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for .php files

`rtrim(substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1),".php");`